# On the (qualitative) behavior of a coupled differential equation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrices, differential-equations

Let $\mathbf{x}(t):=[x_1(t),\dots,x_n(t)]^\top$, $n>1$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a nonnegative matrix and $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a positive vector. Consider the following differential equation
$$\tag{$\star$}\label{eq}
\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) = \mathbf{b}+ A\, \mathbf{\text{sin}}(\mathbf{x}(t)), \quad \mathbf{x}(0)\in\mathbb{R}^n,
$$ 
where $\mathbf{\text{sin}}(\cdot)$ denotes the sine function applied elementwise to a vector.

> **A couple of questions:**
>
> 1. By any chance, does the solution of \eqref{eq} admit an explicit form?
> 2. If the answer to my previous question is no (as I would expect), can we infer some "qualitative" properties on the behavior of the solution of \eqref{eq}? In particular, I would expect that the behavior of $\mathbf{x}(t)$ would be closer to be linear as $\mathbf{b}$ gets larger or the entries of $A$ get smaller? In particular, in the limit case $\mathbf{b}\to \infty$ the solution should tend to $\mathbf{x}(t)\to \mathbf{b}t$; am I correct?

Comment: even the simplest nontrivial 2x2 case does not seem to have an explicit solution.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second question, consider the flow on the quotient space $\mathbb{T}^n = (\mathbb{R}/(2 \pi \mathbb{Z}))^n$.

When $n = 2$, in the unperturbed case, the behavior depends on whether $b_1/b_2$, where $\mathbf{b} = (b_1, b_2)$, is rational or not.  In the former case, the torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ is foliated by periodic orbits, in the latter it is a minimal set.

M. Peixoto in the 1960s initiated the investigation of the structural stability of flows. He gave a  [characterization of structurally stable systems on two-dimensional manifolds](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Structural_stability#Structural_Stability_in_Dimension_Two).  Unfortunately, according to Peixoto's theorem, your unperturbed systems are **not** structurally stable.

But this means only that arbitrarily close there is *some* perturbed system whose phase portrait is different from the unperturbed one (*a priori*, perturbing by adding the terms *as in your question* need not change the picture). However, at least in the case of rational $b_1/b_2$ the phase portrait (periodic orbits alone) seems extremely precarious, and it is highly improbable (to me) that it would remain the same under perturbation.  Perhaps for irrational $b_1/b_2$ there is some spark of hope?